# Karate summary reports not giving combined report for all feature file in 1.4.0 RC2

Tags: api, karate, junit5

I am recently using version 1.4.0 RC2, and I have observed that the karate summary report does not show the test result for all the feature files, but the last one in the list.
Early in one of my projects I was using 0.9.6 and did not face this issue, I was getting all the feature file test results consolidated in my karate summary report.

so I tried running the package in the project were I have 0.9.6 version and can see the consolidated report beeing generated

I check in 1.0.2 and there I can see the issue again

Has there been any change in the way the report is generated? do we need any other tags or dependencies to get the combined result?

```
package com.api.sa;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;

public class runner {
    
    
    @Karate.Test
    @Order(1)
    Karate runPolicySetsGet() {
        return Karate.run("classpath:com/api/sa/AccountsDetails.feature").relativeTo(getClass());
    }
    
    @Karate.Test
    @Order(2)
    Karate runPolicySetsGet1() {
        return Karate.run("classpath:com/api/sa/PasswordExpire.feature").relativeTo(getClass());
    }
    

}
```

Report

[image]

Expect that the Summary contains the result for the Account details also